# Can I use a button connected to an arduino to add text to a file?

Tags: java, c#, arduino, text-files

I'm in high school and we're selling donuts to raise money for one of our computer competitions. In order to figure out when throughout the day the donuts sell the most, I'm trying to come up with an easy way for the seller, our teacher normally, to keep track of when she sells a donut. I instantly thought of my arduinos that I bought just a bit ago. The idea that I came up went something like this:

Whenever someone buys a donut, the seller presses a button on the arduino breadboard. When that button is pushed, the arduino gets the time from itself, and then puts the date and time sold into a text file, either just as line, or into an array. Unfortunately, I have very little experience with my arduinos and have no idea how to do this.

So now I turn to you guys. How would I be able to do this?

Comment: You need to equip your question with a proper code/what you've tried to support it. Otherwise it will be marked as a "low quality question".

Comment: How will you handle a file with your arduino ?

Answer (score 0):

The main question here is... where are you saving the file?

IMHO you have three choices; from easier to harder

1. Leave the arduino connected to a PC and communicate serially with a program which stores the time in a file on the PC.
2. Save the time in the EEPROM inside the Arduino
3. Use an SD card to store the time.

Method 1 is the easiest one. You already have the time and the file support, and you just have to send a serial message whenever the button is pressed. You can even avoid the button: at startup the arduino sends the message and you just have to reset the board at every donut sell. Cons: you have to leave a PC connected to the arduino all the time.

Method 2 is harder: you will need an RTC (real time clock) with a battery to keep the time. At every button press the arduino saves the time to the eeprom. Cons: the eeprom is not very big, so you could fill it. Moreover you will need to read the data from a PC through the arduino serial port, since the eeprom is not accessible, so you'll have to implement also the reading part.

A slight variation of method 2: instead of saving the real time save just the time from the power on (returned by the `millis()` function). This way you don't need an RTC, but you'll have to manually write down the powering time.

Method 3: saving to an external SD saves you the trouble to read the data serially: just use the FAT library and save to a .txt file and you will be able to read the file from your PC. Cons: this is the hardest path, since it involves  using an RTC and an SD.

Anyway there are a lot of examples on the web, so.. Good luck :)